# How to fetch iOS CoreData by Classname

Tags: ios, core-data

I've an iOS project where I'm trying to use CoreData.

In my model, I've two class `ChildA` and `ChildB` who inherit from `ParentClass`.

In my `UITableViewController`, I can easily get all objects with:

`NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ParentClass" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];`

What I'm trying to achieve now is to group results by `Classname`. But I've no idea how to achieve that in my `NSFetchedResultsController` for the param `sectionNameKeyPath`

`NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"?????" cacheName:@"Master"];`

The result I want to use in my `UITableView` should look something like

```
ChildA
   Obj1
   Obj2
   Obj3
   ...
ChildB
   Obj4
   Obj5
   Obj6
   ...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a possible way to achieve that...

I declared two `NSFetchedResultsController` in my `UITableViewController`

```
@interface MMPOITableViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *childAFetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *childBFetchedResultsController;
@end
```

The first one is responsible to manage objects of class `ChildA` and the second one is responsible to manage objects of class `ChildB`.

Then I managed to use `childAFetchedResultsController` or `childBFetchedResultsController` depends on the current section.

Hope it'll help someone else ;)